# Confused about for loops Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to figure this out by watching tutorials on for loops on YouTube and reading material from python and google. But there is still one thing I do not understand.

I don't understand the rules for what goes after the word for in the for loop. Can someone please look at my example code and explain what exactly is happening for this to give different outputs and error on one occasion.

Thanks in advance for any advice :)

```
>>> def my_range(start, end, step):
    while start <= end:
        yield start
        start += step

>>> for x in my_range(1, 2, 0.5):
           print(x)

1
1.5
2.0
>>> for i in my_range(1, 2, 0.5):
           print(i)

1
1.5
2.0
>>> for blabla in my_range(1, 2, 0.5):
           print (blabla)

1
1.5
2.0
>>> for d in my_range(1, 2, 0.5):
           print(d)

1
1.5
2.0

# Why does the three below this comment only print 2.0?

>>> for i in my_range(1, 2, 0.5):
           print(x)

2.0
2.0
2.0
>>> for x in my_range(1, 2, 0.5):
           print(i)

2.0
2.0
2.0
>>> for blabla in my_range(1, 2, 0.5):
           print(x)

2.0
2.0
2.0

# How come I cannot print(t) here? What are the rules for what to put inside those brackets?

>>> for blabla in my_range(1, 2, 0.5):
           print(t)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#70>", line 2, in <module>
    print(t)
NameError: name 't' is not defined

# Now in the following two tests I am suddenly allowed to use t, and even print it? Why? And what is the reason for the outputs being different again?

>>> for t in my_range(1, 2, 0.5):
           print(blabla)

1
1
1
>>> for x in my_range(1, 2, 0.5):
           print(t)

2.0
2.0
2.0
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

The word that you put after `for` in a loop is a variable name. One value yielded by the iterable you're looping on (the part after `in`) gets assigned to the variable name on each iteration.

So, given this loop `for x in range(10)`, the variable `x` will be assigned each number between `0` and `9` in turn. This is a normal assignment, just like `x = 0`, and the variable keeps the last value after the loop ends.

The reason you're seeing strange stuff in your test loops is that sometimes you're looping and assigning one variable, but printing out a different variable. If the other variable is undefined, you'll get an exception. Otherwise you'll repeatedly get the same value (whatever it was last assigned, perhaps by a previous loop).

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped me understand what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

From w3Schools [Python For Loops](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp)

> The range() function defaults to increment the sequence by 1, however it is possible to specify the increment value by adding a third parameter: range(2, 30, 3):

For the first red example: You define a variable x

1. The value of x is 1. 1 is < 2 so the function prints 1.
2. The value of x is incremented by 0.5. 1.5 < 2 so the function prints the value of x = 1.5
3. The value of x is incremented by 0.5. So x is now 2. 2 = 2 so it prints 2
4. The value of x is incremented by 0.5 2.5 > 2 so the print function is not run, and the loop is end.

Every red example is the same, you just define new variables i,blabla,d.
On the first green example you loop over i and print variable x. Variable x will always have the same value(2) until you change it, or unset it.

On the blue example, you try to print an undeclared variable t. Right after that you define t variable by `for t in my_range(1, 2, 0.5) :` that is correct blabla has value of 2 from the last green example.

Comment: Thank you! There was a couple of important things I was unaware of here. Your answer was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You define those variables. You name them.

```
for i in range(0, 5):
    print(i)
```

Will print:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

You've defined `i` to be whatever comes out of the range or list you're iterating over.

Try this.

```
band_list = ['Led Zeppelin', 'Beatles', 'The Who']
for band in band_list:
    print(band)
```

You'll get:

```
Led Zeppelin
Beatles
The Who
```

If you print `band` again, that variable will be set to the last thing in that loop. (It's overwritten each time the loop goes through. So the last one is never overwritten.)

```
print(band)
```

You'll get:

```
The Who
```

Think of a for loop as going from one thing to the next. If you define the variable `i` or `d` `blahblah` or `band` it represents the first thing, then the second, then the third, and so on. And the last item in the list or range 'The Who' or '2.0' isn't replaced by anything because nothing came after it.

Comment: Thank you very much. That pretty much pieced it together for me. I have just started learning Python and it wasn't exactly clear to me that I was defining variables when creating the loop and that the value was kept for next time I used it in a new loop. I am still a bit confused why the second to last test only printed 1 1 1 though. blabla was already assigned to 2.0.

Comment: That THIRD to last test failed AFTER you assigned `blablabla` to 1. You assigned the variable, the loop dropped to the next line, found that `t` had not been instantiated/assigned and threw an exception. The occurrence of assigning `blablabla` to 1 had already taken place in the line above.

Comment: So when you ran the second to last for loop. The program said: Okay, I need to set the variable `t` to the items in [1, 2, .05] as I loop through them. Let's start. Set varialbe `t` to 1. Now, drop down a line and print `blablabla` (which had been set to "1" in the previous loop before exploding). So, `t` was set to 1, it dropped down it printed `blablabla`: "1". `t` was set to 2 and it dropped down and printed `blablabla`: "1". `t` was set to 0.5 and it dropped down to print `blablabla` which is still set to "1". It was never set to anything else.